# Seeking shapefile of Indian electricity grid?

Tags: shapefile, data, india

Does anybody know where I can find a shapefile of the major components of the Indian electricity grid?

Ideally, I'd get transmission/other high-voltage lines, substations, generating units, and transformers. I know there are power maps out there (like [this one](http://www.geni.org/globalenergy/library/national_energy_grid/india/indiannationallectricitygrid.shtml)), but I want to match these transmission lines up with geographical data, so more precise locations would be helpful.

Comment: I somewhat doubt that information is readily available due to security issues.

Comment: The general topic of finding electrical grid components (although not specifically for India) has been discussed on open data SE, and you may find some useful suggestions there. But the short answer is that you will likely not be able to get everything you're asking for. Transmission lines are a strong possibility (try open street map), but the other components are unlikely to be available.

Answer (score 2):

OpenStreetmap seems to have some data:

http://www.itoworld.com/map/4?lon=84.67111&lat=24.56236&zoom=7&fullscreen=true

You can get the full source data of India from [Geofabrik](http://download.geofabrik.de/asia/india.html) , and filter for the items you are interested in.

But don't expect the data to be complete.