# Where can I find data related to hydro power production in india?

Tags: data, india, hydrography

This could possibly include meteorological data/precipitation data aggregated on the district level and power line/ electric transmission infrastructure locations

Comment: The second question within your question is answered by the duplicate.  If you need the other part answered too then I recommend that you [edit] your question so that it focuses only on that part.

Answer (score 1):

Power and Energy data is usually proprietary, I was able to find this data on hydro plants in india : http://www.cea.nic.in/hydro_wing.html

So from that data you may be able to create a point feature class of hydro plant locations.

For Power Lines I was able to find this old question on here:

[Seeking shapefile of Indian electricity grid?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/110020/where-can-i-find-a-shapefile-of-the-indian-electricity-grid)

Which provides this: 
http://www.itoworld.com/map/4lon=84.67111&lat=24.56236&zoom=7&fullscreen=true

http://download.geofabrik.de/asia/india.html

For Climate Data, I dont know of any that comes pre aggregated to the district level, but with your districts and some tools you can probably take data found here and make it work:

http://www.worldclim.org/download

http://www.unep.org/geo/